# What needs to be configured at Prometheus target? What data needs to be served?

Tags: prometheus

I'm following a Prometheus [tutorial on their own site](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/) and I'm a bit confused because the Prometheus server is scraping it's own url. From what I understand, Prometheus can be configured to **scrape** target urls and provides metrics. But what metrics?

I have a service that I want to monitor, let's call service A, that is being consumed by service B. Service B is constantly retrieving data from service A, the source of truth. In service B, I want to build a small in-memory store for data that is being retrieved from service A and it increments a counter for every successful query that is made. As long as this store is incremented at a steady rate, I know that service A is up and running. Can I create an endpoint in service B that exposes this data to Prometheus? IF so, what needs to be returned from this endpoint?

Also, does Prometheus create extra load on the target?